# How to remove html element while leaving the text inside input value untouched?

Tags: html, css, jscript

Need to remove  tags from within an input's value tag.

The element is being generated by the host's CMS so the only way I can remove the bold tags is through running a script.

```
<span id="kkkje30">
<input type="text" id="siF14" class="manFlPassw" value="<b>generated text</b>" maxlength="15">
</span>
```

Comment: try something like this: var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""); Then you could set the value of the input, to the "strippedString"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to remove tag in input value like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').each(function(index, item){
    var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
    var value = $(item).val();
    var removedtag = value.replace(regex, '');
    $(this).val(removedtag);
  });
})
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').each(function(index, item){
    var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
    var value = $(item).val();
    var removedtag = value.replace(regex, '');
    $(this).val(removedtag);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="kkkje30">
<input type="text" id="siF14" class="manFlPassw" value="<b>generated text</b>" maxlength="15">
</span>
```